# Google Hangouts - "Your mic is muted by your system settings" (Jabra Evolve 75)

Tags: google-hangouts

When using Google Hangouts (meet.google.com) with a Jabra Evolve 75 - the error "Your mic is muted by your system settings" is displayed every time I open a hangout, despite the microphone working fine in hangout (and confirmed in "settings").

Screenshot of errors, since there seems to be no documentation of this exact error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ClpQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCCqu.png

The 'learn more' link just takes me to the generic hangouts troubleshooting:
https://support.google.com/meet/answer/7380413

Comment: Confirmed I have that problem too, ALSO with a Jabra. That appears to be the common factor. It used to work fine - but sometimes I had to actually make some noise for it to realise it was not muted. It's 100% unusable for the last few weeks

Answer (score 5):

You need to unmute in the system settings:

- open sound settings
- switch to settings of mic
- open additional settings
- make sure mic is unmuted

Adjust the level and mute status in the levels tab:

[image: adjust level and mute status in levels tab]

Answer (score 0):

### Background

I've recently had this problem, and I found the Windows troubleshooting wizard fixed it and unmuted my microphone.

[image]

### The Fix

Go to Sound settings, and then click troubleshoot button below the mic icon:

[image: Windows Sound Input Troubleshoot]

### Potential Cause

On the previous two occasions, the issue re-occurred is after using Zoom instead of hangouts.

Answer (score 0):

From Google Meet's [troubleshooting guide](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/7380413?hl=en#zippy=%2Cunmute-your-windows-device)

> 1. Open the Sound settings and then click Recording.
> 2. Double-click the microphone.
> 3. Select Levels.
> 4. Check that the microphone is on.
> 5. To raise the volume, move the volume slider and click OK.

You could navigate to these settings easily from Control Panel (not Windows 10 Settings App)

> Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound > Recording

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Ensure that "Jabra Direct" is installed and running on your PC. If not, you will be able to mute the microphone, but not unmute it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).